# Convert each character of a string in bits

Tags: java, string, char, ascii, bit

```
 String message= "10";
        byte[] bytes = message.getBytes();

        for (int n = 0; n < bytes.length; n++) {
            byte b = bytes[n];

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {//do something for each bit in my byte
            boolean bit = ((b >> (7 - i) & 1) == 1);
            }
        }
```

My problem here is that it takes `1` and `0` as their ASCII values, `49` and `48`, instead of `1` and `0` as binary(`00000001` and `00000000`). How can I make my program treat each character from my string as a binary sequence of 8 bits?

Basicly, I want to treat each bit of my number as a byte. I do that like this `byte b = bytes[n];` but the program treats it as the ASCII value.

I could assign the number to an int, but then, I can't assign the bits to a byte.

Comment: 2 is not binary so you'll never be able to take "12" and get "11" base 2 out without doing some math (or using some helper classes).

Comment: They *are* binary sequences of 8 bits.  The character code 1 is 00110001 and 2 is 00110010.  See an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif).

Comment: I know, but I want 1 to be represented as 00000001 and not 00110001.

Comment: Then subtract out 00110000 (which is '0').

Comment: Problem is, it's of type byte[] and I don't know exactly how to substract from it. Also edited original message, since I did a slight mistake.

Comment: Look at this answer -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c/47990#47990 -- and it'll tell you how to get individual bits out of a byte. See the answer by @christopher below for how to turn an string into an int.

Comment: `(byte)(myByteArray[n] - '0')` (The `(byte)` cast is needed to convert the result of the subtract (which will always be `int`) back to a byte (assuming that's what you want).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit messy, but the first thing that comes to mind is to first, split your message up into `char` values, using the `toCharArray()` method. Next, use the `Character.getNumericValue()` method to return the `int`, and finally `Integer.toBinaryString`.

**Example**

```
String message = "123456";

for(char c : message.toCharArray())
{
    int numVal = Character.getNumericValue(c);
    String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(numVal);

    for(char bit : binaryString)
    {
         // Do something with your bits.
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a little verbose. You can just do int myInt = Integer.parseInt(message); then get the bits out as you describe. Once its an int though, you can just do xor each bit to get it out.

Comment: It tells me for-each not applicable expression type.

Comment: If you know it's an ASCII digit, just subtract `'0'` from it.

Comment: @mttdbrd The idea of debate is to produce the best answer. Post a better answer and I'll gladly upvote. :)

Comment: What if I give it as an int, instead of string? For instance int message=0x0001. How can I include that in my program, to take the '1' as 00000001 and use it in my for loop?

Comment: @user3383062 See the comment I gave above. That thread has an excellent answer that tells you how to get each bit out of an int.

Comment: Problem is, I want to treat each bit of my int as a byte. So, if I have 10, my number will be 0000000100000000(and then I will use each of these bits in my program). I just don't know how to treat my number like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
String msg = "1234";

for(int i=0 ; i<msg.length() ; i++ ){
    String bits = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(msg.substring(i, i+1)));
   for(int j=0;j<8-bits.length();j++)
      bits = "0"+bits;
}
```

Now bits is a string of length 8.

1
00000001
10
00000010
11
00000011
100
00000100

You can use getBytes() on the String

Comment: bits needs to be of type byte. I will be shifting its bits in my for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Java`'s [`parseInt(String s, int radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,int%29):

```
String message= "10";
int myInt = Integer.parseInt(message, 2); //because we are parsing it as base 2
```

At that point you have the correct sequence of bits, and you can do your bit-shifting.

```
boolean[] bits = new boolean[message.length()];
System.out.println("Parsed bits: ");
for (int i = message.length()-1; i >=0  ; i--) {
    bits[i] = (myInt & (1 << i)) != 0;
    System.out.print(bits[i] ? "1":"0");
}

System.out.println();
```

You could make it `byte`s if you really want to, but booleans are a better representation of bits...